# count spaces of a line using stack in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I want to count the spaces from an input line. I did it by the following way, but every time it is giving the same output : 0. It seems that COUNT label is not working!!!!!!

```
**MAIN PROC
XOR CX, CX
MOV AH, 1
WHILE_:
INT 21H
CMP AL, 0DH
JE END_WHILE
PUSH AX
INC CX
JMP WHILE_
END_WHILE:
MOV AH, 2
MOV DL, 0DH
INT 21H
MOV DL, 0AH
INT 21H
MOV BL,48
TOP:
JCXZ EXIT
POP DX
DEC CX
CMP DX, 20H
JE COUNT
JMP TOP
COUNT:
INC BL
JMP TOP
EXIT:
MOV AH, 2
MOV DL, BL
INT 21H
MOV AH, 4CH
INT 21H
MAIN ENDP

END MAIN**
```

Comment: `cmp dx, 20h` probably should be `cmp dl, 20h`. `ah` wasn't zero when you `push`ed it.

Comment: @FrankKotler Post that as an answer so that the question can be marked as closed.